# Rotate Rectangle Around Its Upper Left Corner

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, geometry, cgaffinetransform

Simply trying to rotate a rectangle around it's origin, or its upper left corner like so:

[image]

Am using the following:

```
panGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(panGestureRecognizer.view.transform, (M_PI * angle) / 180);
```

But the rectangle is sort of rotating in a big loop. Is there some sort of translation I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the anchor point: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint

```
panGestureRecognizer.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

**Further Reading:** For more advanced stuff you could try some of the tips detailed here for matrix transformations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8536553/563381

Comment: Thanks. I did try this, but it didn't work. Possible I need to set something else as well?

Comment: This should be all you need. And you make an image similar to your expected outcome that shows the actual outcome? Might help me better understand whats going wrong.

Comment: Actually the correct answer is: CGPointMake(0,0),it's the view.layer.anchorPoint (you didn't put layer in the above). If you fix those, will mark answer as correct.

Comment: Opps, sorry for the typo. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Also, have to change CGPointMake(0,1.0) to CGPointMake(0,0) that's what gave me the correct response