# how can i rotate a UIImage around my location

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimage, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView so I want to rotate a UIImage around my current location in the map  . 
is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply a 2D rotate transformation around the point to this view. In this post explain perfectly your problem:

[One step affine transform for rotation around a point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275882/one-step-affine-transform-for-rotation-around-a-point)