# Can I call system's auto rotation method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wanna make screen rotate by clicking a button. However,  due to complex layout and I'm using sizeClass, I don't plan to achieve it by setting views' transform. So can I call system's method. If yes, and how?

Comment: Well you can override but then the user still has to turn the device and trigger it manually if you don't want to make to make it like super convoluted.

Comment: @LinusG.  I got it! So the best solution is to set views' transform?

Comment: @LinusG. I mean I wanna make a view (a lot of subviews in it) rotate like system's auto rotation. So the solution is only to set views' transform?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean with *views' transform*

Comment: @LinusG. There's a view with a lot of subviews in it, and I want to make it rotate like system's auto rotation by touching a button. How to make the view and its subviews layout perfectly after the rotation?

Comment: Oh well you could either use auto layout or calculate positions on screen depending on its width. You could change the layout in the method that is called when the screen rotates. Something with an `NSNotification`. I forgot, sorry.

Comment: @LinusG.  I had used sizeClass with auto layout to layout views in IB, but I don't know how to trigger it. Because the rotation is not the real screen rotation just like a transform!

Comment: Oh so you want to "rotate" instead of actually rotating? So in fact, technically, it is still portrait but it looks like landscape?

Comment: @LinusG. Yes!  Please give me some suggestions

Comment: Thats actually a good idea. Well that's easy. In the button's selector method simply set the new locations. Oh and also you need to rotate the views like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21374041/3397217

Comment: That's why  at beginning I wanna call system's method, if I can call it, it can trigger the auto layout in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
{
     objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
}
```

**However this is a private API.**

Comment: So I have to set views' transform to implement  it?