# Draw a rectangle inside a circle with respect to its center

Tags: ios, geometry, cgpath

I am trying to place a `CGPath` over a circle at a given angle. The path looks more like a rectangle. When I finished creating my path, I move to the center of the circle and draw the path from it. But I want to place the left-center of the rectangle to align with the center of the circle, not the top-left. I guess, I should calculate the origin of the rectangle with respect to the given angle by applying some formula, I have no idea how to do it.

```
 //My logic to draw the circle goes here
....
    //My custom rect drawing logic is inside the CreatePath method
    CGPath customRectPath = CreatePath(size);
    context.TranslateCTM(center.X, center.Y);//I am sure this is where I am doing it wrong
    context.RotateCTM((float)(angle));
    context.AddPath(customRectPath);
    context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.EOFill);
```

The image should explain what I am trying to say.

[image]

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8536553/1971013) I'm sure you can work it out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TranslateCTM` sets the translation of the *top-left* corner of your rectangle, not the midpoint of the left side (which you want). To do this, simply take away *half* the rectangle's height from the `y-offset`:

`context.TranslateCTM(center.X, center.Y - size.Height / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

You should create the rectangle so that it is relative to the rotation origin.

Eg the corners of the rect

```
0, - width / 2      // top left
size , - width / 2  // top right
size, width /2,     // bottom right
0, width / 2        // bottom left
```

Any shape that you intend to transform should be created relative to the intended rotation and scale origin.